# Appium iOS automation using Java : get element using accessibility Id?

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium

I am new to iOS automation using Appium. I can access elements and do automation using XPath like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[3]")).click();
```

I would like to access elements using the accessibility label name given. When using the Appium inspector I can see that the accessibility name is displayed under the parameter **Value** . But How to access this value using Java code?

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the findElementByAccessibilityId(String using) method in Java. More info on it here:

http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/FindsByAccessibilityId.html

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute will return the all the information about the element, you just need to filter what you want, Following code will return the value of the element.

> driver.findElement(By.name("Sign in")).getAttribute("value")